# Can SharePoint 2010 Search crawl email with attachments stored in librairies?

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-server, crawl, sharepoint-email

We use that feature allowing us to send an email to an address defined within SharePoint and store it in a specified document librairy.

We know SharePoint is able to extract the attachment and store it in the library with the proper email, but the client doesn't want that.

He wants the .eml, attachment included.

I crawled that library. I can find my mail with the proper keywords, but it seems that the attachment inside the eml file cannot be crawled. Is there a solution or a workaround to force the crawl to search attachments in the EML ?

Thank you for your wise advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint search architecture unable to crawl email attachments. Either you have to store attachment in different item or different library to available attachments in the search result.

Regards, Jay

Comment: Your Welcome @Jean-NoelPierre